# Pandas dataframe create new rows based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a pandas dataframe of a column of lengths of time in hours and an index of the associated start time. How would I go about limiting the length of time to that of a month and creating a new row for the dataframe if a month is exceeded in an efficient manner? The new row would then have an index of the start of the month and contain the remaining hours.

An example df:

```
              datetime  duration
           0  20-01-2001 03:00       960
           1  01-05-2001 19:00        18
```

with the example output:

```
              datetime  duration
           0  20-01-2001 03:00       285
           1  01-02-2001 00:00       672
           2  01-03-2001 03:00         3
           3  01-05-2001 19:00        18
```

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you gave an example of what your `df` looks like and what you want it to look like.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will create the new rows.  I don't know of an efficient method to do this without calculating these parts separately.

```py
import pandas as pd
df_in = pd.DataFrame({"datetime": [pd.to_datetime("20-01-2001 03:00",
                                                  format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"),
                                   pd.to_datetime("01-05-2001 19:00",
                                                  format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")],
                      "duration": [960, 18]})

def split_durations(df):
    count = 1
    # repeat until no more hours > hours in month
    while count > 0:
        # get start of next month (time part as 00:00:00)
        df["next_month"] = (df.datetime + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin(1)).dt.normalize()
        # hours to end of month from datetimes
        df["hours_to_eom"] = (df.next_month - df.datetime) / pd.Timedelta(hours=1)
        # duration after month end
        df["remaining_duration"] = df.duration.sub(df.hours_to_eom).clip(lower=0)
        # number of new months created
        count = df.remaining_duration.gt(0).sum()
        # either hours to end of month or duration, minimum of
        df["duration"] = df[["hours_to_eom", "duration"]].min(axis=1)
        # combine data
        df_out = pd.concat([df[["datetime", "duration"]],
                            df[["next_month", "remaining_duration"]].rename(
                                columns={"next_month": "datetime",
                                         "remaining_duration": "duration"})
                            ]).sort_index(kind='merge')
        # drop any rows where duration is 0
        df = df_out[df_out.duration.ne(0)]
    return df


df_out = split_durations(df_in)
```

```py
df_out
#Out[]: 
#             datetime  duration
#0 2001-01-20 03:00:00     285.0
#0 2001-02-01 00:00:00     672.0
#0 2001-03-01 00:00:00       3.0
#1 2001-05-01 19:00:00      18.0
```